# Does the Iranian Navy have long-range phased array radar systems?

Tags: military, iran

Iran routinely unveils new defense products. Most of them are alleged to be fake. For instance:
 1. [Fake stealth jet](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2013/02/iran-new-stealth-fighter-jet-fake/318714/).
 2. [Fake development of jet engine](https://www.defenceaviation.com/2016/09/meet-owj-irans-first-indigenous-fighter-jet-engine.html)
 3. [Fake development of jet fighter](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/the-buzz/why-irans-fighter-jet-ripoff-just-fake-news-19487)
...
and, so on. Why they are fake is easily understandable.

This [2013 Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNWgYSppDAw) is apparently a report from an [Iranian News Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNWgYSppDAw). The description claims:

> The Iranian Navy unveiled its new long-range phased array radar system called 'Asr' [...]

The description lists other announcements about the development of the technology.

**Does Iran have such technology on their ships?**

This question stems from the fact that aerospace technology are much more complex. Radar technology is not that much. In addition, Iran is the [2nd largest](https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php) (Turkey is #1) research paper producer in the Muslim world. But, given so many fake products displayed by the Iranian government, have they really manufactured their own Radar system?

For instance, the device at **0:14 of the video** looks totally fake.

Comment: I made a significant edit. It no longer asks whether Iran could, hypothetically, create such technology independently, and now sticks to facts: Do they have it or not?

Comment: which could start by considering if they even have a likely need for it.

Comment: @jwentig If we are to judge by the tweeter account of president Trump, yes, they do need it indeed. And probably they need a better one than that.

Comment: You realize that long wave radar is basically WWII tech?  The only thing new would be making it phased array.  Long wave was abandoned because it needs huge antennas and even then has very poor resolution.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Long *range*, not long *wave*...